# How to store select table values as php to use in sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I'm using select values in a form which I want to store and upon submitting the form, a table is displayed with the results of my sql query but using the select values to query the database. My current html is here:

```
<body>
    <div id="top-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Favourites</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Messages</a></li>

            <li id="mainheading" style="align left"><a      href="Home.html"><strong>BookSmart</strong></a></li>
```

```
    </div>

    <div id ="search_elements">

        <form method="post" action="test.php">    
            <img  src="UniSelect.jpeg">

                <select name ="university">
                    <option selected disabled>Select a university</option>
                    <option value="ucl">UCL</option>
                    <option value="kings">Kings College</option>
                    <option value="imperial">Imperial College</option>
                    <option value="lse">London School of Economics</option>
                </select>

        <img height="250px", width="600px" src="PriceSelect.jpeg">

                <select name="rent">
                    <option selected disabled>Select a weekly rent price</option>
                    <option value="50">0-£50</option>
                    <option value="100"> £100-£150</option>
                    <option value="150">£150-200</option>
                    <option value="200"> £200+</option>
                </select>
        <img height="250px", width="600px" src="RoomSelect.jpeg">

                <select name="roomtype">
                    <option selected disabled>Room Type</option>
                    <option value="50">University Halls</option>
                    <option value="100"> Studio</option>
                    <option value="150">Flat</option>
                    <option value="200"> Shared Accomodation</option>

                </select>


        <img height="250px", width="600px" src="DistanceSelect.jpeg">

                <select name="distance">
                    <option selected disabled> Selecet a distance from         the university</option>
                    <option value="1">0-1 miles</option>
                    <option value="3"> 1-3 miles</option>
                    <option value="5">3-5 miles</option>
                    <option value="6"> 5+ miles</option>

                </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>



</body>
```

And the code I currently use to query the database and display the results in a table is:

```
<p style ="text-align: center" id="php_style">
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    session_start();
    $counter_name = "counter.txt";
    // Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
    if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
      $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
      fwrite($f,"0");
      fclose($f);
    }
    // Read the current value of our counter file
    $f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
    $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
    fclose($f);
    // Has visitor been counted in this session?
    // If not, increase counter value by one
    if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
      $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
      $counterVal++;
      $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
      fwrite($f, $counterVal);
      fclose($f); 
    }
    echo  nl2br ("You are visitor number ".$counterVal. " to this site     \n Today's date is ". date("d/m/Y"));

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","booksmart_properties");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
else
{
    echo "we connected";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']
    {
    $university = $_POST['university'];
    $rent = $_POST['rent'];
    $roomtype = $_POST['roomtype'];
    $distance = $_POST['distance'];


    //Now you can do anything with variables , you can put them inside     query like this : //
    // $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = '$universit' "); // 
    // Note : this is dangrous way to do a query in PHP you should prevent something called SQL Injection , search for it  //
    // Perform queries  

    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ListedProperties 
    WHERE PropertyType = '.$roomtype' ");
    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>PropertyType</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Rent Price</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PropertyType'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['RentPrice'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";

    }))

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I was wondering how the values from the select table can be stored as php variables and inserted into the query for use when the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok its easy , First you have to give every Select tags a name like this :
i will do it for one and you do it for the others :

```
<select name="university">
      <option selected disabled>Select a university</option>
      <option value="ucl">UCL</option>
      <option value="kings">Kings College</option>
      <option value="imperial">Imperial College</option>
      <option value="lse">London School of Economics</option>
</select>
```

After you give every `SELECT` tag a name give your input now a name like this :

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
```

Now its time to receive the values from the form and save them inside PHP variables .

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","booksmart_properties");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    else
    {
        echo "we connected";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit')
        {
        $university = $_POST['university'];
        $rent = $_POST['rent']; // i assumed that you name the second Select tag RENT and the Third ROOMTYPE and the last DISTANCE  
        $roomtype = $_POST['roomtype'];
        $distance = $_POST['distance'];

        //Now you can do anything with variables , you can put them inside query like this : //
        // $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = '$universit' "); // 
        // Note : this is dangrous way to do a query in PHP you should prevent something called SQL Injection , search for it  //
        // Perform queries  

        $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ListedProperties");
        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>PropertyType</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Rent Price</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['PropertyType'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['RentPrice'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";

        }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Important links and subjects that will help you in the future :

- [Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) You may want to look at this .
- [SQL INJECTION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: should the value of action be the separate php file where the php is executed or should it be below the html. I've tried the current code out but I just get a blank screen?

Comment: It dose not matter where the php code exist , as long as there is a php code to receive the data from the form , can you give me the full code you are trying to execute so I can see where is the error ? @Adam

Comment: I've edited my post so that the php file and the html file are both there

Comment: OK I will take a look at them in 5 min stay tuned

Comment: @AdamKona can i use PDO instead of mysqli ?

Comment: I managed to fix it, there were a couple mising brackets here and there and a couple value errors on my part but the code works now. Thanks for all your time and help

Comment: @AdamKona no problem sir . It was nice to help you =) good luck with your project .

Answer (score 0):

You can use form method like this link  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

And use this link to insert my sql to database
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp